# Subscribe to Observable returning wrong values

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm building an application using [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). My file structure looks like this, all folder are in the same directory. My problem is that, when I subscribe to `startActivity` method, I get back two different values. It looks like the singleton is not working and I'm getting back two different instances of an object.

> Folder structure

```
- activity.ts
- main.ts
- renderer.ts
```

> renderer.ts

```
import Activity from "./activity";

const activity = Activity.getInstance();

activity.startActivity().subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log("Renderer: " + data);
    }
);
```

> activity.ts

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


class Activity {
    private static _instance: Activity;

    public static getInstance() {
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
    }

    public startActivity() {
        return Observable
            .interval(this.config.timeInterval)
            .map(() => {
                return Math.random();
            });
    }
}

export default Activity;
```

> main.ts

```
import {app} from "electron";


app.on("ready", () => {

    const activity = Activity.getInstance();
    activity.startActivity().subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("Main: " + data);
        }
    );
});
```

> Results

```
Renderer: 0.599276120749491
Main: 0.5746604589633764
```

So, why am I not getting the same data from both `console.log()` calls?
PS: I'm quite new to Node.js world, so I'm sure it's something trivial..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cause of Electron's architecture based on multi process. Main / Renderer runs on **different process**, means you can't directly share object between as same as doesn't provide singleton object as well, cause main process creates one object and renderer process also creates one for is own as well. If you'd like to establish single state between process, you should consider synchronization via passing values between ipc protocol.